# Remove dynamicly transformed images

Tags: craft3, assets, console

Is it possible to remove/delete all, via transformer, generated images? Leaving the original be.

Craft creates new directories to handle these images. So i could create a script in combination with a crontab that deletes said directories.

My question is if craft already has this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But as far as i researched, their currently is no built in feature to archive this.

I setup my server with a cronjob that runs the following script periodically: `find <image-dir> -type d -regextype sed -regex ".*/_[0-9]\{3,4\}x[0-9]\{3,4\}.*" -exec rm -rv {} \;`

This will delete all folders that look like this example: `_650x430_center_center`.